# Class, Interface, Prototype, and else

Tags: class, oop, interface, prototype

I'm creating a JavaScript Framework for making applications in the classic Object-Oriented Programming (so with classes/interfaces instead of only prototypes). However I still have a problem with giving names to those.

For instance :

```
var Bidule = function() { /*...*/ } ;
Bidule.prototype = { /*...*/ } ;
```

Is Bidule a **OOP Class** as a class is a constructor ? Or is it only a **constructor** ?
As classes don't have prototypes, I don't think it could be called a true class.

So it means I should call them both 'Constructors'. However, what about an interface or an abstract class ? What is the correct word if they aren't constructors ? And is an interface a kind of class ?

I've designed constructor functions, classes and interfaces in my Framework. However I need a name to regroup all of theme so we may build one of those like this :

```
var Bidule = new _NAME_.Class(/*...*/) ; // Where _NAME_ is the name of the container of class/function/interface.
```

I was thinking of "*Concept*" but I'm not sure and would like to know your opinions.

---

I also named "*visibility*" the common word for describing public/private class,
"*type*" for static/abstract/interface/singleton/final class. Are those correct ?

---

And one last question : Is there a difference between the verb '*extend*' and '*inherit*' ?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is not a traditional OO language, it is prototyped. Some concepts about OO cannot be applied to js for this reason.

`Bidule` is your **type**, so it is your "class". The constructor is the **function** you assined to the variable.

```
var Bidule = function() { /*...*/ } ;
Bidule.prototype = { /*...*/ } ;

var obj = new Bidule();
obj.foo = 'bar';

var obj2 = new Bidule();
obj2.foo = 'foo';

alert(obj instanceof Bidule); // true
alert(obj2 instanceof Bidule); // true
alert(obj.foo); // bar
alert(obj2.foo); // foo
```

Javascript does not support abstract classes or interfaces and no, interfaces are not some kind of classes. Interfaces defines contracts, or **what** your class does, but do not specify **how**.

Extend and inherit have the same meaning in this context.

Comment: Thank you for all those answers.
So if `Bidule` is a type, how should I call "static/abstract/interface/singleton/final" ? "_attributes_" of class ?

Comment: Final, static and abstract are **modifiers** of a class. Interface is a **contract** that a class will sign when implement it. Singleton is a **design pattern** that provides a single instance of the object for the whole application.

Comment: Sure, it's just that with one key I could switch to one of these five words.
But you answered my question. :) Thanks again !